# UICollectionView refreshing issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

In an iOS app I have a `UICollectionView` which has 100 (or 80, or 40) cells to start with.
At the beginning all is fine, the layout is OK and the size of each cell is also right, smaller if there is 100 and larger if there is only 40 cells.

Inside the app the user has the possibility to change the number of cells to 100 (or 80, or 40).
When the number changes the layout and size of each cell should be changed accordingly. But that part does not work as expected.

When the user changes the number of cells this code is executed:

```
myCollectionView.reloadData()
myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

And for some reasons something is not working. Should I do something more or different in the code above?
The number of cells is right, but the size of the news cells is messed up and I am not totally sure about the layout (positionning).

As far as the UICollectionViewDelegate protocol is concerned, I only implement one method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    .........
}
```

For the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol, I implement the following:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     let cellSide = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 3 / CGFloat(brain.getSide()! * 4)
    return CGSize(width: cellSide, height: cellSide)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 6.0
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width / (CGFloat(brain.getSide()!) * 4.4)
}
```

It seems like the methods above are working fine at start, giving adequate values. But they do not even seem to be called when the user changes the settings.

Comment: Could you post what you have in your tableView delegate methods?

Comment: This is a UICollectionView, not a UITableView. I updated the post, hoping it gives you the information you need.

Comment: try to simply reload collectionview, discard  this function and check myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

Comment: What do you mean by "reload collectionview"? I am already doing "myCollectionView.reloadData()" as you can see in my post. Do you mean something different?

Same, what  do you mean by "check myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()"? This is also what  I am already doing as you can see in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by solving the problem, using cell prototypes with a different cell identifier for each size I need and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this reloading method

**Objective-c**

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                                            [myCollectionView reloadData];
                                          } 
                              completion:^(BOOL finished) {}
];
```

Swift-3

```
myCollectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
            myCollectionView.reloadData()
        }, completion: { (result: Bool) in
        })
```

Comment: I am working in swift. But I am going to try. Is it different from what I am doing? Calling: myCollectionView.reloadData() ?

Comment: Thanks. But NG.

1) It has to be:
myCollectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
            self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
        }, completion: { (result: Bool) in
        })
Or it will not compile. Then if I run I get this crash:


2017-03-28 18:53:18.671116 APP[909:254156] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView ......... incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
....
(lldb)